# How do I hide text in a GUILayout.TextField in Unity (I'm using c# to do this)?

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, passwords

I'm trying to make a login screen to test a login/out system in Unity, but I don't know how to hide the text. I'm able to make just about everything else but I'm not sure how to hide the text to make it like a password field.
Here is what I have so far:

```
GUILayout.Box("Password:");
password = GUILayout.TextField(password, 15);
```

What do I need to add/change to hide the GUILayout.TextField... text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a ready-to-use function in unity for that.

```
GUILayout.Box("Password:");
password = GUILayout.PasswordField(password, '*', 15);
```

See also: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUILayout.PasswordField.html

Comment: Like so? Sorry I'm not used to places like this :)

Comment: Perfect! Thx. Maybe now's the time to get used to it :-)